# MYSQL combining, counting and separating instances of rows with same id but different values

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a query that looks like

[image: Start]

with the query being written as such:

```
SELECT username, exerciseId, frustrated, bored 
FROM affecttutor.selfreportfrustration 
order by username;
```

and I am trying to make it look like this

[image: Finish]

what would be the possible ways to go about doing it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. Consider whether there's scope to redesign your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select 
   username,exerciseid,
   count(case when frustrated='Y' then 1 end) as frustrated,
   count(case when frustrated<>'Y' then 1 end) as notfrustrated,
   count(case when bored<>'N' then 1 end) as bored ,
   count(case when bored='N' then 1 end) as notbored
from affecttutor.selfreportfrustration
group by username,exerciseid
```